# how to het customer pick date for electron product, example, amusement park ticket

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, programmatically

I'm trying to sell tickets electronically. Consider like an amusement park, or parking lot tickets. No worries about assigned seats or limited dates / times. I can handle checking if it is sold out, but this would be a rarity. I do need the customer to be able to pick the date for the tickets and store that. If I'm reading it right, the product attribute "date" is a specific date for a product and not selectable per order. If I'm right about this, is there a way to store the ticket date for a product on a per order basis? Or would this require writing a custom module that stores the date in a custom database table?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a product attribute, you can add a "Custom Option". These store the customer supplied value on the cart item: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-options-custom.html